# Postfix with ip address instead domain name

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I have virtual server without domain name yet. On server is Ubuntu LAMP installed. I will have domain name later. I can access on server via public static ip address. I want make only simple sending email from php script from this server. I want use Postfix. But I read that Postfix needs FQDN. Before I start install and configure Postfix I want know if is possible  **use ip address instead domain name** for Postfix.
Very thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to make postfix send mail to the Internet without FQDN. It can be set up to exchange mail between local users, though, but that's obvoiusly not going to help you. The reason behind this is quite simple: The vast majority of the mail servers are verifying peer's identity on SMTP connection using reverse DNS lookup. If your IP has no nice DNS name assigned, then your mail is quite likely to be considered spam. So even though you might manage to bypass FQDN requirement, your recipients still may not receive your mails. It can even be dangerous, as your IP may get stuck into spam lists after that.

I see two options for your here:

1. Wait for the correct domain name to be associated with your IP
2. Or use mailbox on an established public service like gmail or hotmail to send mails from. This will play well as a temporary solution until you got your DNS record in place.

Comment: I installed Postfix using by http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKO4MfOpDVs. And I don't change configuration files however. Now mails are normal sending using by mail(). But you're right, some mail servers don't like stragne sender addresses and blocked this. I tried three mail servers and only one haven't problem with these mails delivery.